# What might cause windows to be redrawn exceptionally slowly on Ubuntu 22.04 running nvidia graphics?

Tags: nvidia, graphics

I've seen the following problem a couple of times now running 22.04 but have never seen it before on my Ubuntu installation (running same hardware).

You can see a [video of this in action at youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bmGm4ZukAWs).

You will see that windows move extremely slow as I drag them across the screen.

Here are details of my system:

[image: system details]

It's not the main processor, it is that suddenly graphics processing seems to be effected.

What might cause this?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that this stopped occurring when I closed an app which is [using a component WebView2](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/).

I then started the app again and the odd slow behavior started occurring again.

It seems that the WebView2 component causes this to happen.

I'm also running FireFox 107.0 64-bit but even if I close that (and all other apps) and only run the app which contains the WebView2 component do I see the problem.